# Table not formatted Markdown editor in @toast-ui/vue-editor

Tags: javascript, vue.js, markdown, text-editor, toast-ui-editor

How can I improve table formatting in my Vue app utilizing @toast-ui/vue-editor? All aspects work flawlessly, except for table formatting. Is there a solution available to rectify this issue? Below is the code snippet of the component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <editor
            ref="toastUiEditor"
            :options="textEditorOptions"
            initial-edit-type="wysiwyg"
          />
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
   data() {
    return {
      editorText: 'initial',
      placeholder: '',
      textEditorOptions: {
        previewStyle: 'vertical',
        language: 'language',
        usageStatistics: false,
        placeholder: '',
        height: '300px',
        toolbarItems: [['heading', 'bold', 'italic', 'ol', 'ul', 'table']],
      },
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

And this is how the table is currently displayed:

[image]

And this is how I want the table display, I don't want to be exactly like this, but I mean the space to be more formatted

[image]

Comment: The question is extremely vague since asking to "improve" something is subjective.  We see the actual result, but what's wrong about it?  What is the expected result that you want? Please be detailed in your description.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, I will update the question with what I expect